# Can we switch off RLS for certain users?

Tags: powerbi

My dataset has sales and users table. The sales table has userid that links it to the users table.

I have configured dynamic RLS filter on the users table such that only the loggedin user sales data is shown.

I want to disable RLS when certain users are logged in. Example: management head user so they can see all the data without RLS.

Is there any way to achieve this? Otherwise this leads to me having to create duplicate report and dataset.

Comment: Service or Report Server? If service, add them as a member, not a viewer role

Comment: Power BI service. The access is provided via app. Adding user as member to workspace will allow app user to override the RLS?

Comment: You can add another level to user by adding a new column user_type. Then you can decide the logic for RLS base on that new column.

Comment: Do you mean have RLS on 2 columns?

Comment: I've deleted my answer, you can't set member role  to not edit, that was under the old workspace experience